# Conditional display style

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items having this structure:

```
items = [ {name:"name1",value:"value1",status:"new"},
          {name:"name2",value:[new_val, prev_val],status:"changed"},
          {name:"name3",value:"value3",status:"deleted"},...]
```

The status can be either: "new","changed" or "deleted".
What I need to do is to ng-repeat the list of items and display them as follows:

- If `status === "new"`: display the name in "green"
- If `status === "deleted"`: display the name in "red" and struck through
- If `status === "changed"`: display the name in yellow, the first value
   in red and struck through, the second in green (as the new value)

My code looks like this:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td ng-class="{'deleted-entry': item.status === 'deleted', 
                 'changed-entry': item.status === 'changed', 
                 'new-entry': item.status === 'new'}">
    {{item.name}}
  </td>
  <td ng-if="another condition">
    <i ng-if="item.status !== 'changed'">
      {{item.value}}
    </i>
    <!-- <i ng-if="item.status === 'changed'" ng-class="changed-entry">{{item.value[0]}}{{item.value[1]}}</i> -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

I don't know how to display the values side by side, each with a different class style in the `status==="changed"` case.
Here are my css classes:

```
.deleted-entry {
   text-decoration: line-through;
   color: red;
}
.changed-entry {
  color: yellow;
}
.new-entry {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: if you always have 2 values, 'old' and 'new' for a case when it was changed, then simply separate them and use appropriate classes for each: `<i ng-if="item.status === 'changed'" class="deleted-entry">{{item.value[0]}}</i>  <i ng-if="item.status === 'changed'" class="new-entry">{{item.value[1]}}</i>`

Comment: Thank you. But now I have a problem that the color does not change, I think it is because of the table style. Do you know how to force the text inside td tags to get the style I defined?

Comment: Did you use `ng-class` or `class` with my example? Because I have a [working version](https://plnkr.co/edit/LUIrBNw2X6ZMgHa0ZPbw?p=preview). Additionally you can try using `ng-switch` for different types of statuses, e.g. `ng-switch="item.status"` with `ng-switch-when="'changed'"`